# Simple action methods in processing

Tags: processing

original code given:

```
int[] x = {50,61,83,69,71,50,29,31,17,39};
int[] y = {18,37,43,60,82,73,82,60,43,37};
beginShape();
for(int i=0;i < x.length; i++)
    vertex(x[i],y[i]);
endShape(CLOSE);
```

Add the appropriate methods so the star will appear at a random location. This method does NOT allow the user to select the location of a star.

Use a "for" loop in the setup method to call the star() method 100 times to produce 100 stars on the screen.

This is what I have so far...something obviously isn't right

```
void setup()
{
    size(800,600);
    background(#0F4D7C);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        randomStar();
    }
}


void randomStar() 
{
    pushMatrix();
    translate(0,0);

    int[] x = {50,61,83,69,71,50,29,31,17,39};
    int[] y = {18,37,43,60,82,73,82,60,43,37};

    beginShape();
    for(int i=0;i < x.length; i++)
        vertex(x[i],y[i]);
    endShape(CLOSE);

    popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Please provide compilable code.

Comment: You say something obviously isn't right- what's not right about it? What does this code do? What did you expect it to do instead? Also, I don't see any randomness in any of this code.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `draw()` method. I've also moved `translate(x,y)` to the for loop. Check it out:

```
void setup()
{
  size(800, 600);
  background(#0F4D7C);

  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(random(width), random(height));
    randomStar();
    popMatrix();
  }
}

void randomStar() 
{


  int[] x = {
    50, 61, 83, 69, 71, 50, 29, 31, 17, 39
  };
  int[] y = {
    18, 37, 43, 60, 82, 73, 82, 60, 43, 37
  };

  beginShape();
  for (int i=0; i < x.length; i++)
    vertex(x[i], y[i]);
  endShape(CLOSE);
}
```